# Flutter Android Studio Device Loading Issue: Device Daemon Fails to Start. Please Check Configuration and Restart IDE

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, emulation, daemon

[image]I am encountering a problem with Android Studio; the devices are not loading when I start it. I have run 'flutter doctor', and it shows no issues. I've also tried upgrading Flutter, reinstalling the Flutter plugins, and even reinstalling Android Studio, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was fixed by reinstalling Android Studio and cloning the project in a new location. By the way, the old (original) project still opens with this bug, while at the same time, the new project in another window works as expected without any issues.